# Generic polymorphism: create a variable of whatever type and use it

Tags: c++, generics

I believe this is also called "type erasure". Consider the following not too minimal and not working code example:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>


std::pair<int, int> foo(int);
std::pair<std::string, std::string> foo(std::string);


struct S
{
    S(int);
    S(std::string);
};



int main()
{
    const auto some_bool{ false };

    const auto data =
    [ some_bool ]
    ()
    {
        if(some_bool)
        {
            return foo(42);
        }
        else
        {
             return foo("fourty-two");  // error: different return type
        }
    }
    ();

    const auto s{ data.first };

    // use s and data.second regardless of it's type
}
```

I would like to:

- keep `data` constant
- not duplicate all the following code inside an `if...else`
- avoid templates if possible because of the horrible error messages and the need to implement in a header
- avoid putting the rest of the code in a separate function because it is on the same level of abstraction as creating `s`.

What would be a nice approach?

Comment: Have a look at [`std::variant<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and/or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), depending on how much erasure you need.

Comment: `if constexpr` can be used as `some_bool` is a constexpr  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01946cfb6bccbf94).

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to use `.first` and `.second` on `data`, you will need a pair of two type-erased values, as you need to avoid erasing the fact that it is a pair. i.e `std::pair<erased_type, erased_type>`

In your example, you know the list of types ahead of time, so you should use [`std::variant<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to create a type that can contain one of the known alternatives. If you do not know the list at compilation time, you can use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead.

```
using int_or_string = std::variant<int, std::string>;
using data_type = std::pair<int_or_string, int_or_string>;
```

Next, you can force the lambda to return this erased type and let the various return values be implicitly converted to it:

```
[...]
    using int_or_string = std::variant<int, std::string>;
    const auto data =
    [ some_bool ]
    () -> std::pair<int_or_string, int_or_string>
    {
[...]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton for introducing me to C++17 concepts! However I ended up using a generic `auto foo(auto && ){ static_assert( std::is_same<A, B> ) }` instead of the lambda. It's weird how `auto foo()` is equivalent to `template<typename T> foo()` while `auto foo = [] () {}` is equivalent to  `deduced_type foo()`.